# Show that the function, $f(z)=e^{y}e^{ix}$ is nowhere analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=e^{y}e^{ix}$

$=e^{y}(\cos x+i\sin x)$

$u(x,y)=e^{y} \cos x$

$v(x,y)=e^{y}\sin x$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-e^{y} \sin x$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=e^{y} \cos x$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=e^{y}\cos x$

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=e^{y}\sin x$

We see that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are not satisfied anywhere in the z-plane except at $z=n\pi$ where n is an integer.

We need to check if $f^{'}(z)$ exists at $z=n\pi$

$f^{'}(z)=Lt _{\delta z -> 0}\frac{f(z+\delta z)-f(z)}{\delta z}$

$\delta z = \delta x + i \delta y$

Comment: Firstly, you may want to edit so there is an actual question you're asking. Secondly, here's another approach: recall that the CR equations say that $\partial f/\partial\bar z = 0$. Notice that your function is $Ce^{\bar z}$ for appropriate $C$. This will simplify your calculations a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $z=x+iy$ and

$$f(z)=e^{i\bar{z}}.$$

The C.R. equations are equivalent to the single equation...

Answer (score 3):

Your computations with Cauchy-Riemann's equations are enough to show that $f$ is nowhere analytic. (Analytic, or as many prefer, *holomorphic*, means that $f'$ exists on an **open** set.)

The computations you've left out would check if $f'$ possibly exists at $z=n\pi$, but even if it does, $f$ is still nowhere analytic.